# Need help about running a program in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, compiler-errors

I am new in programming in VS201O and OpenCV. I am trying to implement SIFT algorithm. Could anyone tell me what are the errors standing for? if someone needs the whole program I'll send it to him.
Thank you in advance. Your help will be really precious.

Here are the errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: sift, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  sift.cpp
1>c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sift\sift\sift.cpp(2): warning            C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sift\sift\sift.cpp(3): warning C4627: '#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sift\sift\sift.cpp(4): warning C4627: '#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sift\sift\sift.cpp(5): warning C4627: '#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sift\sift\sift.cpp(83): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you read it? It says `did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?` which gives you all you need to search for in your research and debugging phase.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `#include <StdAfx.h>` as the **first line** of every .cpp file in your project. That's because StdAfx.h is the precompiled header, and some special rules apply to it. So you have to include it even if you don't use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solved a lot of the errors but I still have one: c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sift\sift\sift.cpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
I this came from the linker settings?

Comment: Right-click your project in **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties**, then go to **Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Preprocessor | Additional Include Directories**, and in the textbox enter the full path of the folder where the "opencv2" folder is located.

Comment: Hi again, thank you for your replies, i'm going slowly to the solutions, but i stil have some problems, this time when i run it it show me the following error:     opencv_core243.lib(opencv_core243.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' ...............Hope someone can help .